# memory bound kernel and compute bound kernel in GPUs

Tags: kernel, gpu, nvidia

What is *"memory bound kernel and compute bound kernel in GPUs"*?

Is this related to performance of GPUs?

Answer (score 7):

Informally, the kernel is memory-bound if the most of kernel time is spent in executing memory instructions. In contrast, the kernel is compute-bound if most of operations are ALU-FPU instructions. GPUs have high memory and compute bandwidth and can be suitable for both categories. The terms are used for categorization and to indicate which optimization techniques may improve the performance of application significantly.

There are different optimization tips for the workloads of each category.

For example, for memory-bound workloads:

- Exploit shared memory
- Memory access coalescing
- Memory camping.

For compute-bound workloads:

- Reduce branch divergence
- Interleave computation between ALU-FPU and
  SFU
- Provide enough independent instructions to exploiting ILP.

Comment: whats memory camping, cant find any source for it.